# Using parallel or tasks with web-services and database connections

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, parallel-processing, task

***Explanation***
I have a scenario where i have 1000's of clients and their information is stored in different areas, I need to retrieve their Transactions from one place 
their balance from another and their information from a local source

The first 2(transactions and balance) uses webservice's and the local information is a normal database `SqlConnection`

I retrieve the list of balances before I run through each client because every client has 1 balance entry, but the clients transactions has to be retrieved per client and the rest of the calculations depend on that

I need to run through each client and do a number of things on their accounts like give bonuses if a transaction matches certain criteria or deduct, give monthly free credits and so on. 
Each of these actions that needs to be done on the accounts require a new database or web call to update that resource

so code would look something like this(psuedo)

```
var Clients = getfromDB();
var Balances = webservicecall.getbalances();

var clientswithbalances = from balance in Balances
                    join customer in Clients on balance.Idnumber equals customer["IdNumber"]
                    orderby Convert.ToInt32(customer["CustomerId"])
                    select new
                    {
                        CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(customer["CustomerId"]),
                        Name = customer["Name"].ToString(),
                        Idnumber = customer["Idnumber"].ToString(),
                        Balance = Convert.ToDouble(balance.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    };
foreach (var user in users)
{
   var transactions = webcalltransactions(user.Idnumber);
   //calculations that use more webservices and database calls updates and inserts
}
```

**Question**

I tried parallel.foreach but it gave problems with the webservice and database calls
What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: If you have to wait smth in your logic (webcalls, harddrive, database), async task is better. If you want to do many calculations for each case, you should to use multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Console app to test this but works only on .net 4.5>=. This can be done on other versions as well but needs some changes.

```
 class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                DoStuff().Wait();//As you can see my main thread is blocked if wait is used;
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


            public static async Task DoStuff() 
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                var clientsTask = GetFromDBAsync(); //DON'T await
                var balancesTask = GetBalancesAsync(); //DON'T await
                await Task.WhenAll(clientsTask, balancesTask);//If the implementation is async dose a parallel call the nameing convention is async methods have Async at the end MethodAsync

                var clients = clientsTask.Result;
                var balances = balancesTask.Result;

                var users = Enumerable.Range(clients, balances).Select(i=>new { IdNumber = i }); // I am mocking your query so you can see what is happening

                var usersTasks = users.Select(user => GetClientAsync(user.IdNumber)).ToArray();

                var userServerData = await Task.WhenAll(usersTasks);//You can do Task.WaitAll(usersTasks) if your method can't be async but this will block you main thread and can be buggy ;

                foreach (var user in userServerData)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(user);
                }
                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Total time {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);//Total time is close to 2s rather then 22s if everething is sync;
            }

            public static Task<int> GetFromDBAsync()
            {
                return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => 0);
            }

            public static Task<int> GetBalancesAsync()
            {
                return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => 20);
            }

            public static Task<int> GetClientAsync(int clientId) 
            {
                return Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => clientId);
            }
        }
```